# How to dismiss android alert dialog itself via setOnEditorActionListener?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, kotlin

There is an alert dialog which contains a password `EditText` and I'm trying to perform the action which is the same as pressing positive button after the keyboard RETURN button is pressed.

In my MainActivity:

```
fun enterPwd() {
    val builder = android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    val password = EditText(this)

    // some layout attributes about password are omitted

    password.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO
    password.setOnEditorActionListener({
        if(id == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) { v, id, event ->
            doSomthingFunction()
        }
        false
    }) 
    builder.setView(password).setMessage("message")
                .setPositiveButton("confirm", { doSomethingFunction() })
                .setNegativeButton("cancel", { dialog, i -> }).show()
}
```

In the latter doSomethingFunction() in `setPositiveButton`, the builder would dismiss automatically after the button is pressed. However in the previous one, the dialog is still there. I had tried to pass `dialog = builder.show()` and then dismiss by `dialog.dismiss()` right after `doSomethingFunction()` in the `setOnEditorActionListener` (appended as following) but it had no effect. How do I dismiss this dialog after the return key is pressed?

```
val dialog = builder.show()
password.setOnEditorActionListener({
    if(id == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) { v, id, event ->
        doSomthingFunction()
        dialog.dismiss()
    }
    false
})
```

Comment: How many edit text's are there in our Alert dialog?

Comment: Only one, the `password`. It was also the only view that I added to the builder

Comment: try to place setPositiveButton() in the place of doSomethingFunction().

Comment: Try `Dialog.this.dismiss()`

Comment: is it working whitney?

Comment: @Groco I tried your suggestion but both Dialog and AlertDialog had no object of `this` in kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ram's comment inspired me. Since I've already defined the action when positive button is clicked, I just get the dialog from the builder on declaration, and then simply call `performClick()` on the positive button, and everything works fine.

That is:

```
val dialog = builder.setView(password).setMessage("message")
            .setPositiveButton("confirm", { doSomethingFunction() })
            .setNegativeButton("cancel", { dialog, i -> }).show()

password.setOnEditorActionListener({
    if(id == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) { v, id, event ->
        dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).performClick()        
    }
    false
})
```

Answer (score 2):

try to place setPositiveButton() in the place of doSomethingFunction()

Comment: Not very sure what you meant. I tried to replace `builder.setPositiveButton("confirm", { d, i -> doSomethingFunction() })` in the original line `doSomethingFunction()` and nothing happend. I think the `setPositiveButton()` only did the setting, so the positive button remained unpushed at all.

Comment: so, create a button programmatically  and write your code when button is clicked, and hide that button, now place button.perform click in place of doSomethingFunction.

Comment: it will help you... @whitney

Comment: Thanks @Ram for inspiring me on solving the question. Finally I made some modification on the code, however the thought is quite similar.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please dismiss dialog after call doSomthingFunction() .

Comment: I had tried it by there is no use. That was why I come here for an answer.